# Raspberry PI Nas. 2 same size hard drives but different free space - SOLVED

Tags: hard-drive, nas

I have a Raspberry Pi Nas. I used to have 2x Seagate IronWolfs installed but 1 failed just after a year (was not impressed). So I just replaced it with a WD Red Plus. Both are 4TB so I synced my data from the Wolf Drive to the new WD Plus. The thing is, now they both have the same data on them the free space shows different.

I used rsync to Sync the data.

df Output

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sde1      ext4      3.6T  3.4T  3.7G 100% /media/HD3
/dev/sdd1      ext4      3.6T  3.4T  190G  95% /media/HD4  <------ Difference
```

rsync output

```
sudo rsync -vrhn --delete --progress --ignore-existing "/media/HD3/" "/media/HD4/"
sending incremental file list

sent 1.98M bytes  received 2.48K bytes  793.70K bytes/sec
total size is 3.73T  speedup is 1,881,163.11 (DRY RUN)
```

fdisk output.

```
Disk /dev/sdd: 3.64 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: TerraMaster
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A6F1A012-15A9-4DD7-9405-29B60213F715

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdd1   2048 7814037134 7814035087  3.6T Linux filesystem

-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Disk /dev/sde: 3.64 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: TerraMaster
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A540ED30-3F58-BA4A-93D3-6D83AACCA8B1
```

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sde1   2048 7814037134 7814035087  3.6T Linux filesystem

I am still learning Linux so I was wondering if anyone knew why the free space is different? If this is because the drives are different makes I can live with that, but I would like my 100GBs+ back if not.

I started looking into lost+found and deleted and recreated it on HD3 but nothing changes.

I tried manually checking each folder on HD3 and HD4 with du and they all matched.

**Update**: I popped the NAS onto a Raspberry Pi as this had gparted.  Gparted said the available space was the save yet `df -h` still says different.  Very strange.

Comment: Does `df -h` show the same results as root and as non-root?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to take a look,  yes I get the same results as root,

root@osmc:/home/osmc# df -h | egrep "HD3|HD4"
/dev/sdc1       3.6T  3.0T  459G  87% /media/HD3
/dev/sdb1       3.6T  3.0T  646G  83% /media/HD4

I have been reading for answers and tried a badblock run but got good results,

Checking for bad blocks (read-only test):
Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)

I now remember that while reading how to format this new drive I did run the below.

dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=10

I ctrl-c'd it stupidly.  I might have caused this.

Comment: That doesn't look like the same result at all! The numbers are literally different. (But unfortunately they're different in a way that _wasn't_ what I was expecting, so it must be a different issue than I thought.)

Comment: I found the reason,  It was the ext4 reserved space.  HD4 was set to 0 so I set HD3 to 0 and now they match.  Thanks again for taking an interest.

Comment: So submit an answer instead of editing your question and providing the solution in the body of your question.  Which should be removed, because answers to a question, should not be contained in the body of the question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "I found the reason....It was ext4 reserved space on HD3". The problem experienced by the author has been resolved by their own research.

Comment: @Ramhound: That's usually a case for posting their own answer, not for deleting the question outright. We used to have a built-in close reason for that; it was deliberately removed many years ago.

Comment: @Phill: Right, that's why it looks different for root vs non-root.

Comment: @u1686_grawity - My intention was to reverse the close vote if it was self-answered. Got the correct action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason....It was ext4 reserved space on HD3

```
osmc@osmc:~/Scripts$ tune2fs -l /dev/sdb1  | grep 'Reserved'
Reserved block count:     0
Reserved GDT blocks:      1024
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)


osmc@osmc:~/Scripts$ tune2fs -l /dev/sdc1  | grep 'Reserved'
Reserved block count:     48837719
Reserved GDT blocks:      1024
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)

#Set HD3 to 0
osmc@osmc:~/Scripts$ sudo tune2fs -m 0 /dev/sdc1
tune2fs 1.46.2 (28-Feb-2021)
Setting reserved blocks percentage to 0% (0 blocks)

osmc@osmc:~/Scripts$ tune2fs -l /dev/sdc1  | grep 'Reserved'
Reserved block count:     0
Reserved GDT blocks:      1024
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)

osmc@osmc:~/Scripts$ space
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1       3.6T  3.0T  646G  83% /media/HD4
/dev/sdc1       3.6T  3.0T  646G  83% /media/HD3
```